# Selector [WARN] Error in I/O with host java.io.EOFException in Apache Kafka 8.2

Tags: apache-kafka

Our Apache kafka environment has 1 - zk, 3 - servers. heap size of 1800 MB on each server. I am trying to produce 1000, 20mb files to see performance of Kafka.

I am getting:
[PDT] 2015-03-23 13:53:50 Selector [WARN] Error in I/O with host
java.io.EOFException
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFrom(NetworkReceive.java:62)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:248)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:192)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:191)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:122)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

This error I am getting sometimes @ 997th message and sometimes @ 999th message. There is no pattern.

Thanks and appreciate your time!

Comment: I caught the same bug on AWS instance with single broker and 500kb payload message to kafka.

Answer (score 1):

This has been solved here https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-3205

Try increasing the connections.max.idle.ms in the broker config (the brokers in kafka 0.9 have a default of 10 minutes)